# I tried this code for LSTM and GRU. But the GRU is not working

Tags: python, neural-network, lstm

I am not sure where i am wrong in this code. My goal is to train my dataset for binary classification using LSTM and GRU.
[the output comes with module wrapper and GRU not executing please check the image][1]

````
    
        #BUILD THE MODEL
        top_words = 10000
        embedding_vecor_length = 32
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=X.shape[1]))
        #model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(GRU(100,dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True))
        model.add(LSTM(100,dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
        #model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam',
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
        print(model.summary())   
        model.summary()


    ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/14pyl.jpg
````

Comment: This question needs focus.  What isn't working?  Also, a reproducible example is much more likely to get attention

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: please check now,image attached